# eclipse osgi: how to load class from a specific bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, equinox, osgi-bundle

I have two bundles both active in the framework. Each of them has its version of a set of classes under the same full name, for example, org.eclipse.jface.util.ILogger. In my code, if I write

```
System.out.println(ILogger.class.getClassLoader());
```

I can see the class loader is from one of the bundle. My problem is I need to use that class from the other one, not the "default" bundle picked up by the osgi framework. That is, when I write the code like

```
ILogger logger = new ILogger(){}...
```

I need the logger to have the type defined in the other bundle. Is there any way to do this? I am using Eclipse 4.4. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After playing with it for a while, I got a way to do it. On the 'Dependency' tab of the manifest file, leave one bundle as the 'Required Plugins' and put the package in use from the other bundle in 'Imported Packages'.